# Signup using Flutter is not working even after adding sha keys correctly

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, debugging, firebase-authentication

I/flutter (19906): PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null)

Comment: I have tried deleting debug.keystore, creating new,flutter clean and again adding sh keys(updated google-services.json too). I have also tried decreasing dependency versions

Comment: Are you in release mode? It is a different SHa1 key.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.